# Ember Data: How to access model values after find()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I access the data from a model after a `find()` method? 
In Ember-Data 1-0-Beta I can request data from my API via `user = this.store.find('user',1)` but how can I get the username of the user for example? Older tutorials achieves this with `user.username'` or `user.get('username')` but it seems to be that this doesn't work anymore?

I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zGsC/4/ (line 21/22)

After submitting the form the username should be written to the console, but its undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically problem is that you are trying to access properties before model is resolved. You can use then method to wait for model resolution
here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zGsC/5/

```
this.store.find('user', 1).then(
        function(resolveduser) {
            console.log(resolveduser.get('username')+' from then');     
        }
    );
```